# IIS NO ME MUESTRA LA APLICACION

Tags: iis

¡Hola a todos!

Necesito ayuda, configure mis aplicaciones en IIS, pero cada vez que voy a examinar la aplicacion, no me muestra nada, le doy a inspeccionar y me devulve un codigo 200. Alguien sabe que puede ser?

Adjuntos fotos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! 200 es que esta todo correcto.. sin mas informacion, imposible saber que pasa...